# Output specific value user enters in a textarea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea that gets the value of what the user inputs and outputs something else (kind of like a chatbox). The only problem is that if the user types "/command hello". I only want "hello" to be displayed and not the /command part. 
I have the following code below, but it isn't working (my mistake on that):

```
var message = "/command " + value;
    var userinput = document.getElementById("thisinput").value; 
        if (userinput == message) { 
          $('#text').html(value);   
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to remove anything between `/` and a space

```
var message = "/command " + value;
var userinput = document.getElementById("thisinput").value; 

if (userinput == message) { 

    $('#text').html(value.replace(/\/.+\s/g,''));   

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/83NP6/)

Comment: One last thing. How can I make the value, whatever the user inputs and not just simply "hello". i.e: If the user inputs /command bye (then "bye" will show up) or any other command

Comment: Just remove `if (userinput == message)`

Comment: I did that, still no luck :/... That just makes the hello appear when I type in the input box.